# How to get the visible text from password EditText (after PasswordTransformation - dots)?

Tags: android, testing

I have a password field with "Show password" checkbox and I want to write an integration test for it. How to check that EditText is indeed masked?

Comment: maybe you could do a `getInputType()` and check if `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` is set?

Comment: @st0le you can change `EditText` behavior by calling `setTransformationMethod()` on it. `InputType` stays the same. Of course I can check if `getTransformationMethod()` is null and that's actually what I'm doing inside the handler. But you see the problem. What if I'll write custom transformation? It would be much better to check what's going on on the screen.

Comment: try this http://nikshits.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/code-to-show-password-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what the transform displays with TransformationMethod.getTransformation(CharSequence, View). Instead of checking for null, you should actually run the transform, and make sure that the "textShown" is what you expect.

```
// EditText editText;
CharSequence realText = editText.getText();
CharSequence textShown = editText.getTransformationMethod().getTransformation(realText, editText);
```

Comment: That's interesting. That's not an integration test but better than nothing.

Comment: When I want to test my "show password" checkbox `getTransformation()` throws a NullPointerException because `getTransformationMethod()` returns null. Things would be much simpler if I could just check the visible text :(